# Errors copying files to external drive

Tags: macos, backup, video, external-disk

I back up my data on NTFS Windows formatted external hard drives (different brand names), cloning each drive to protect against hardware failure. I copy from Mac, Windows, Linux, or Android machines onto one HDD and then make a clone of the HDD with my Mac OS X. I buy the HDDs in pair so they are also physically the same.

I was not aware of the challenges of copying to Windows NTFS HDDs with Mac OS X, and copy-pasted across HDDs without special care. I have had the `XtraFinder` app installed and apparently it allows me to copy onto NTFS without warning or error messages.

But there are problems with some of the copied files (The problems have nothing to do with a size limitation, as this can happen with files of just a few MBs).

Example of problems: I have 2 identical hard drives straight out of the box (brand new WD Ultra Passport, not faulty), HD1 and HD2. First, I copy a video from my Windows computer onto HD1. Secondly, I copy the same video from HD1 to HD2 using the Finder on Mac OS X. Result: The video can be played off HD1 but not off HD2. Whether I try to play the video on the Mac or a Windows or Android machine, same result. So the video copied from HD1 to HD2 appears to be seriously corrupted.

The corruption is a little subtle because `FreeFileSync` does not detect differences between the files on the HDDs. It's only when I try to play the video from the cloned HDD that I get an error message.

1. Is there a way to detect the corrupted files?
2. Is there a fix for the corrupted files?

I have tested this with mkv and mp4 video formats and standard image formats (photos taken with my cameras or phones). Some videos are copied without trouble, other videos are broken after being copied. With images, problems tend to affect a random number of them rather than all of them, maybe 1 in 20 or so. There are no problems at all if I copy with my Windows machines.

This problem has occurred with a dozen or so hard drives. They are formatted as "Windows NT Filesystem" (as read from "Get Info" menu) The problem has occured with previous versions of the OS (Mavericks and Mountain Lion). I have usually backed up with FreeFileSync, to copy large number of files at a time, and the problem has occurred that way too, not just copy-paste via the Finder.

---

MacBook Air, OS X Yosemite (10.10.3)

P.S. I have asked the question on [apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28260070#28260070), but have not received answers at the time of posting here.

Comment: Can you add these details to your question - comments are ephemeral & can be deleted at any time. Also add what you are using to enable write to NTFS on the Mac.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful info: If I cut and paste a file (or several files) "too quickly" from one directory to another of my external hard drive, I occasionally get an error message and the file disappears. I can retrieve it by running a Disk error check on my Windows machine. Strange. I have learned to wait 2 seconds after doing "cut" and before "paste", and the problem disappears.

Comment: You can't 'cut' in the Finder.

Comment: @ Tetsujin, can you clarify? By cut-paste I mean that I use ``command+X`` and ``command+V`` combinations. No apparent problems with, say, PDFs. Under the ``Edit`` menu of the Finder, there is a ``Cut`` command.

Comment: It works in apps, but you cannot Cut a file in Finder. Pick any file, look at the Edit menu, Cut is greyed out. Cmd/x ought to just beep.

Comment: It's not greyed-out here. I have the ``XtraFinder`` installed. I think that's why I can cut and paste. I'm going to assume that the cut-paste bug comes from ``XtraFinder`` then. Thanks for pointing this out. At any rate, the problem exists if I copy-paste with FreeFileSync...

Comment: @Tetsujin, "add what you are using to enable write to NTFS on the Mac": I do not know how to answer this one: I have not knowingly done anything, I have always assumed I could copy to NTFS "out of the box", since it appeared to be working.

Comment: then the test would be to see what happens when you're *not* using Finder mods - & no, Mac can read but not write to NTFS 'out of the box'

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have uninstalled the ``XtraFinder`` and copied a simple test file via the Finder onto my external drive. It does get copied onto the drive, but when I open it instead of the text "test" it reads "utf-8"!

Comment: I'm guessing it wasn't a plaintext file; it was rtf, but the wrong extension. You need to concatenate all this extra info into your original question

Comment: It was a text file created with the textEdit app and with extension .txt

Comment: TextEdit creates RTF files by default, regardless of whether they have the .txt extension or not. You can disable that under Preferences.

Comment: @tubedogg, thanks so that's cleared up then! :-)

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have rewritten the question taking into account what you have told me! Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: My gut feeling [with nothing really to back it up] is still whatever is enabling NTFS writes - it can't be XtraFinder if you've uninstalled it - if it's something ancient like Fuse, that would be prime suspect

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have not knowingly installed Fuse. And after I removed ``XtraFinder`` I could no longer copy onto my NTFS Windows drive. I can't find info about NTFS on the XtraFinder help page, but I have sent a message to them to ask. I don't plan to use my Mac to copy anymore until I find a workable solution. My priority is to replace broken files by sane ones, taking into account that the sane and broken files are randomly distributed on the 2 drives (I would grab either HDD randomly and then clone with FreeFileSync, so the sane files are not all on the same HDD!)